# How to convert between Key and String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm making an extension on Dictionary, just a convenience method to traverse a deep json structure to find a given dictionary that might be present. In the general extension of a Dictionary, i'm not able to subscript because i give a String instead of a Key

```
extension Dictionary {

    func openingHoursDictionary() -> Dictionary<String,AnyObject>? {   
        if let openingHours = self["openingHours"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
         // traverses further and finds opening hours dictionary 

        }
        return nil
    }
} 

Error: String is not convertible to DictionaryIndex<Key, Value> 
on self["openingHours"]
```

How can i make a `Key` from the `String` `"openingHours"` or check the dictionary for ths string?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Because a Swift dictionary' key doesn't need to be String. In fact it can be any type as long as it implements Hashable protocol. The extension has to be working with all kinds of dictionaries, some of which may not use String as key type. Thus self["openingHours"] is not legal for them.

Comment: Creating an extension on Dictionary for this task doesn't seem like the right approach.  It would be better to wrap your Dictionary inside an Object that represents your data

Comment: I found out now that indeed it was possible using a cast from String to Key using `as`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check at runtime if the string is a valid key for the dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func openingHoursDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject]? { 
        if let key = "openingHours" as? Key {
            if let openingHours = self[key] as? Array<AnyObject> {
                // traverses further and finds opening hours dictionary 
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

But this will "silently" return `nil` if called for other dictionaries
like `[Int, AnyObject]`.

If you want the *compiler* to check if it is safe to subscript the
dictionary with a string then you have to use a (generic) function:

```
func openingHoursDictionary<T>(dict : [String : T]) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
    if let openingHours = dict["openingHours"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
        // traverses further and finds opening hours dictionary 
    }
    return nil
}
```

It is (currently) not possible to write `Dictionary` (or `Array`) 
extension methods that apply only to a restricted type of the
generic parameters.

Comment: Worked perfectly, so i gues its the `"openingHours" as? Key {` that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the `String` as `Key` using `"openingHours" as Key`

```
if let pickupPoints = self["openingHours" as Key] as? Array<AnyObject> {

}
```

Downside is that if doing this i will get a crash if i have a `Dictionary<Int,AnyObject>` and use the method there.

```
0x10e8c037d:  leaq   0x362aa(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failure"
```

Comment: Is this safe at runtime? What if the dict itself doesn't even use String as Key?

Comment: Maybe create a Dictionary<Int, String>?

Comment: What do mean create that? I need to check if Dictionary responds to String subscripts.

Comment: The current extension should be working if used as Dictionay<String, AnyObject>. Since extension will affect all the dicts created, I think it's necessary to check it it's safe for Dictionary<Int, AnyObject> and Dictionary<Double, AnyObject> and so on.

Comment: Agreed, but how do you check a dictionary for if its safe to subscript it with something other than String?

Comment: Hmmm...you got me. I need to check some documentation for this.

Comment: updated the answer with the concrete crash i get when doing this on Dictionary<Int,AnyObject>